# React Mathjax2 does not work on React version 17

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, mathjax

I previously run recat-matcjax2 on react 16. It worked fine. But when update the react version 16 to 17 it does not work perfectly.

I am getting a couple of error.

These are two error files.

[image]

[image]

Trying to implement :

```
import MathJax from 'react-mathjax2';
const equation = '(a+b)^2';

const MathJax = () => {

return <MathJax.Context input='ascii' key='math'>
                           
          <MathJax.Node inline>{equation} </MathJax.Node>

       </MathJax.Context>
}
```

My `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
   MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {delimiters: [['$','$']]},
    "HTML-CSS": { 
      linebreaks: { automatic: true },
      mtextFontInherit: true,
      availableFonts : ["STIX"],
      preferredFont : "STIX",
      webFont : "STIX-Web",
    },
    CommonHTML: {
      linebreaks: { automatic: true }, 
      mtextFontInherit: true 
      },
    SVG: { 
      linebreaks: { automatic: true }, 
      mtextFontInherit: true
     }
  });
    </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML"></script>

  <title>LMS App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`react-mathjax2` hasn't been updated in 3 years.

You can try a new library that I have written called [`better-react-mathjax`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax) that is meant to be used with up-to-date React 17. You can use both MathJax version 2 and 3 with it.

Here's an example with `better-react-mathjax` that accomplishes what you want with MathJax version 2:

```
export default function App() {
  const config = {
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [["$", "$"]],
      displayMath: [["$$", "$$"]]
    }
  };

  const equation = "$(a+b)^2$";

  return (
    <MathJaxContext config={config} version={2}>
      <MathJax inline>
        {equation}
      </MathJax>
    </MathJaxContext>
  );
}
```

To do the same but with MathJax version 3, you can use:

```
export default function App() {
  const config = {
    loader: { load: ["[tex]/html"] },
    tex: {
      packages: { "[+]": ["html"] },
      inlineMath: [["$", "$"]],
      displayMath: [["$$", "$$"]]
    }
  };

  const equation = "$(a+b)^2$";

  return (
    <MathJaxContext config={config} version={3}>
      <MathJax inline>
        {equation}
      </MathJax>
    </MathJaxContext>
  );
}
```

Some things to note:

- You feed the MathJax configuration right to the React context component and you don't have to add it to a `script` tag like you did in your example. With your config, (as given to `MathJax.Hub.Config`), this translates to:

```
...

const config = {
    tex2jax: {delimiters: [['$','$']]},
    "HTML-CSS": { 
      linebreaks: { automatic: true },
      mtextFontInherit: true,
      availableFonts : ["STIX"],
      preferredFont : "STIX",
      webFont : "STIX-Web",
    },
    CommonHTML: {
      linebreaks: { automatic: true }, 
      mtextFontInherit: true 
      },
    SVG: { 
      linebreaks: { automatic: true }, 
      mtextFontInherit: true
     }
  }
...
<MathJaxContext config={config} version={2}>
...
```

- You need to supply the delimiters in question in the string (`$...$`).
- Version 3 is the default so `version={3}` is redundant in the second example.
- The default is to use the MathJax default config so the only reason that we need to supply a config in my simple examples is that we use a non-default delimiter for Latex inline math (default is `\(` whereas we use `$`). This all comes from how MathJax works and has nothing to do with `better-react-mathjax`.

Here are working samples:

- [Example with version 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/user-example-2-kii5c)
- [Example with version 3](https://codesandbox.io/s/user-example-3-uikql)

Comment: Works well fast-reflexes. But i can not  use version three in the same process that you provided. Thanks a lot. Have any extra privileges on version three?

Comment: You can use version 3, just set the version prop to 3 and supply a proper version 3 config. I used version 2 because I thought that was what you wanted :)

Comment: Can you provide version three configuration?

Comment: Have to change any into the public.html file?

Comment: I added an example with version 3. In the html file, you should remove the `script` tag with the MathJax configuration AND the `script` tag where MathJax is imported (this is handled by `better-react-mathjax`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more last question, have any extra benefit into version 3?

Comment: There are pro's and con's. Version 3 is much smaller and very different from version 2 (I mean the code, not the results) but in some cases, when dynamically updating math, I see more flickering with version 3 than in 2. I recommend you to start with 3 and only switch to 2 if you run into problems of any kind where it seems that version 2 performs better :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231916/discussion-between-mijanur-rahman-and-fast-reflexes).